# I need a symfony 2 example for drop down select box

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony 2. I have a table categories and a table products. Each product is linked to a category with a categoryid field in product table. I want that the category select box should populate at product form inside a select box (combo box) and the list of categories should come from categories table. If i save the product form and re-open the form to edit then category should be auto-selected that i had saved during creating the new product.

I have really spent a lot of time to search such example but could find. Can someone please give me such example or link to such tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). Here is an example:

http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Choices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#reference-forms-entity-choices)

you should use an Entity form type (it may be useful to override __toString of the category entity) or if you don't want to expose too much stuff you should use [data transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)